# Check if value exists in array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this data

```
    var selectedValue = [];
    selectedValue.push({0:'Data A'});
    selectedValue.push({1:'Data B'});
```

I want to check if my new data is already exists in that array. I'm trying to use `includes()`

```
function inArrayCheck(val) {
  console.log(selectedValue.includes(val));
}
```

Then i try another way

```
function inArrayCheck(val) {
    if (Object.values(selectedValue).indexOf(val) > -1) {
   console.log(val);
    }
}
```

both of them returning `false` when i input Data A

Comment: What is `selectedValue` here?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the values in objects? Why not just `selectedValue.push('Data A')`?

Comment: If you have an array of objects, you should use the same property names in all the objects, not different properties. E.g. `selectedValue.push({key: 0, value: "Data A"})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find a value from an object which is inside an array. You can try like so:

```js
var selectedValue = []; // this is an array
selectedValue.push({0:'Data A'}); // here you push an object to the array
selectedValue.push({1:'Data B'}); // to find the value later you need to find it inside the object!
// above three lines can also be written like so and are the same
// var selectedvalue1 = [{0:'Data A'}, {1:'Data B'}];

function inArrayCheck(val) {
  selectedValue.forEach(function(element){
    if (Object.values(element).indexOf(val) > -1) {
        console.log('found value: ' + val);
    }
  });
}

inArrayCheck('Data A');
```

if you want to use includes you need to have an array like so:

```js
var selectedValue = [];
selectedValue.push('Data A');
selectedValue.push('Data B');
// above three lines can also be written like so and are the same
// var selectedvalue1 = ['Data A', 'Data B'];

function inArrayCheck(val) {
  console.log(selectedValue.includes(val));
}

inArrayCheck('Data A')
```

Answer (score 2):

Objects will not be equal unless they have the same reference, even when they have the same key/value pairs. You can do the comparison after converting the objects to string using `JSON.stringify` with limited capability, like the order of elements in the object and the case of strings matters:

```js
var selectedValue = [];
selectedValue.push({0:'Data A'});
selectedValue.push({1:'Data B'});


function inArrayCheck(val) {
  return selectedValue.some(obj => JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(val))
}

console.log(inArrayCheck({0:'Data A'}))
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to go trough each value. You can also use find() function, to check if array have a value which sutisfy your condition.